# Flush stdout in DrScheme?

Tags: scheme, io, racket

I can do it in Java, Python, Haskell... how do you do it in DrScheme? A customary google search didn't yield the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is MIT Scheme, not DrScheme, but have you tried [flush-output](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/ftpdir/scheme-7.4/doc-html/scheme_15.html)?

Comment: Yes, `flush-output` is the name that PLT uses too.  If you search the docs you'll find it: http://docs.plt-scheme.org/search/?q=flush-output

Answer (score 0):

If you use the R6RS language, you can use [flush-output-port](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-9.html#node_sec_8.2.10) ([PLT docs](http://docs.plt-scheme.org/r6rs-lib-std/r6rs-lib-Z-H-9.html#node_idx_712)). It's also specified in the [SRFI-82](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-82/srfi-82.html).